# Custom change on ng-table pagination click event in angular?

Tags: angular, pagination, ngtable

I have to make a custom change on ng-table pagination click event in angular, but i'm not finding the event of the click of pagination, does any one knows how i can custom this event?

I want to make this: when i change the page the scroll of the page come back to the top.

Answer (score 3):

The event is 'onpageschanged'. But you need 'NgTableEventsChannel' service to work
The doc for that is https://ng-table.com/api-docs/classes/ngtableeventschannel.html#onpageschanged

Example:

```
ngTableEventsChannel.onPagesChanged(somefunction(), $scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

on `click` event you can call event handler in that event handler you can scroll to top as

```
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

and in event handler you can do as

```
onClick(){
     scroll(0,0);
}
```